# Result of 'File.createNewFile()' is ignored

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm not sure why this is but in my IDE, for `file.createNewFile();` I'm getting `Result of 'File.createNewFile()' is ignored` for it which I've no idea what I should be doing

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class SQL {

    public Connection connection;

    public SQL(File file) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile(); // Result of 'File.createNewFile()' is ignored
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch(Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static Code Inspection in your IDE for  `createNewFile` might be complaining this because `createNewFile` returns a boolean value. This is in place so that you have a way to determine if the creation of file is successful or not and act accordingly. Right now the boolean result is not assigned to any variable, so it's ignored.

Ideally you should check the result of `file.createNewFile()` and validate whether file actually got created before moving on to setting up connection.

```java
// Create File
boolean fileCreated = file.createNewFile()
// Validate that file actually got created
if (!fileCreated) {
    throw new IOException("Unable to create file at specified path. It already exists");
}

// Proceed to setting up connection
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 2):

The `createNewFile()` method returns a boolean (`true` or `false`).  `false` indicates that the file already exists.  `true` indicates the file did not exist, and was created.

The warning you are seeing in the IDE is just letting you know that you are ignoring that value, which might be ok depending on your requirements.  An alternative might be somehting like this:

```
if(file.createNewFile()) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a good idea to check the return value of the `createNewFile()` method. If it returns false, then it means the file already existed. This may not be what you expected, because the file is being used for specifying the database URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to replicate your issue to get that specific error message. It should be noted though that `File.createNewFile()` *only* works if a file of the same name does not already exist. I would instead recommend doing this to check if the file already exists:

```
public class SQL {
    public static Connection connection;
    public SQL(File file) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:/users/capoo/Desktop/file_test.txt");
        if (!file.createNewFile()) {
            throw new IOException("File already exists");
        } else {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch(Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I'm unable to replicate your issue to get that specific error message." - It isn't really an error.  It is a warning.  It may be that you have that warning turned off in your instance of IntelliJ IDEA, but I believe it is enabled by default.  I am able to trivially reproduce it.  The warning happens any time a return value is ignored, not just this particular method call.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown As I am not using IntelliJ IDEA, that makes quite a bit of sense! Thanks for clarifying for me.

Comment: Apologies.  I misread the original question.  I thought the question was specifically about IDEA, but the question just says IDE.  That was my mistake.